# How to pass an unescaped string interpolation into a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I am passing !{movies} to a main.js file but every time I call it, x is null.

```
script(src='../javascripts/main.js' id="load" x=!{movies})
```

main.js

```
var script_tag = document.getElementById('load');

var x = script_tag.getAttribute("x");
 console.log(x)//console returns null
```

Comment: Not familar with this `script()` func. Is this something new? Doesn't seem to have proper syntax even it did exist.

Comment: @GetSet ```script()``` is from pugjs which is a HTML templating engine

Comment: Ok. Have you checked the dev console for errors? Have you checked also if `script_tag` is null or undefined.

Comment: @GetSet Yes. Interestingly, when I replace ```!{movies})``` with an arbitrary string ```"green"``` there is no error. The object messes things up.

Answer (score 1):

fixed it

```
script.
      var x = !{movies};
script(src='../javascripts/main.js' id="load")
```

main.js

```
console.log(x)//correctly logs data
```

Comment: Nice. So basically `x` couldnt be a param to `script()`?

Comment: @GetSet `script()` isn't a function.